# Solr data import config for JDBC

Tags: mysql, postgresql, solr, jetty, driver

For the data import handler I have moved he mysql and postgresql jar files to the solr lib directory (/opt/solr/lib).

My issue is in the data-config.xml I have put two datasources, however, I am stuck on what to put for the driver values and the urls.

```
<dataSource name="mysql" driver="<driver>" url="<url>" user="<user>" password="<pass>" />
<dataSource name="postgresql" driver="<driver>" url="<url>" user="<user>" password="pass>"/>
```

Is anyone able to tell me hat I should be putting for these values please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL
Driver - `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`
URL - `jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname`

Postgresql
Driver - `org.postgresql.Driver`
URL - `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/xxxxx`